# I am trying to find start and ending sequence with below pattern,

Tags: python

'Machine_Start',
'Machine_stop',
'power_volt5v',
'Mains_off',
'Mains_on',
'Machine_start',
'power_volt5v',
'Mains_off',
'Mains_on'

In the above example, i see there is matching pattern for the first 2 strings, 'Machine_start, Machine_stop'. However, i dont find the matching sequence on the 6th line 'Machine_start'. The next line should be 'Machine_stop'.

How can i find this using python and append to the line number 7 as 'Machine_stop'.

Can someone help

Comment: So you need to insert `Machine_stop` after every `Machine_start` if it's not already present? Btw, please check your data: `Machine_Start` and `Machine_start` are not the same thing – is the variation present in the original data? (And while you're at it, please [format your code as code with backticks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
strings = ['Machine_start', 'Machine_stop', 'power_volt5v', 'Mains_off', 'Mains_on', 'Machine_start', 'power_volt5v', 'Mains_off', 'Mains_on']
i = 0
cur_len = len(strings)
while i < cur_len:
    if strings[i] == 'Machine_start' and (i == cur_len - 1 or strings[i + 1] != 'Machine_stop'):
        strings.insert(i + 1, 'Machine_stop')
        cur_len += 1
    i += 1
    
print(strings)
```

**Explanation:**

What the `while loop` does is that it loops over each element, and if there's a case where the current element is "Machine_start" and the next element is not "Machine_stop", then it inserts "Machine_stop" to that position. We also have to increment the length as we go to stay within bounds.

In the `if condition`, you'll notice that I have `(i == cur_len - 1 or strings[i + 1] != 'Machine_stop')`. This basically checks if we're currently on the last element before checking the next element (to prevent an "Index out of bounds" error / `IndexError`). The code segment after `or` isn't evaluated if the code segment before `or` is already satisfied.